# Is there any example for sending file through sleekxmpp?

Tags: python, xmpp

I have read several documents and posts in stackoverflow, I did't find any example for sending file or image with `sleekxmpp`.I have read the code in `file_transfer.py` provided in `sleekxmpp` package, But i am unable to use that code.If anyone have or know example for sending file through sleekxmpp plese let me know.Thanks in advance!

Here is my code that i tried to send file with sleekxmpp

```
import logging

from sleekxmpp import Iq, Message
from sleekxmpp.plugins import BasePlugin
from sleekxmpp.xmlstream.handler import Callback
from sleekxmpp.xmlstream.matcher import StanzaPath
from sleekxmpp.xmlstream import register_stanza_plugin, JID
from sleekxmpp.plugins.xep_0096 import stanza, File


log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class XEP_0096(BasePlugin):

    name = 'xep_0096'
    description = 'XEP-0096: SI File Transfer'
    dependencies = set(['xep_0095'])
    stanza = stanza

    def plugin_init(self):
        register_stanza_plugin(self.xmpp['xep_0095'].stanza.SI, File)

        self.xmpp['xep_0095'].register_profile(File.namespace, self)

    def session_bind(self, jid):
        self.xmpp['xep_0030'].add_feature(File.namespace)

    def plugin_end(self):
        self.xmpp['xep_0030'].del_feature(feature=File.namespace)
        self.xmpp['xep_0095'].unregister_profile(File.namespace, self)

    def request_file_transfer(self, jid, sid=None, name=None, size=None,
                                desc=None, hash=None, date=None,
                                allow_ranged=False, mime_type=None,
                                **iqargs):
        data = File()
        data['name'] = name
        data['size'] = size
        data['date'] = date
        data['desc'] = desc
        if allow_ranged:
        data.enable('range')

        return self.xmpp['xep_0095'].offer(jid,
            sid=sid,
            mime_type=mime_type,
            profile=File.namespace,
            payload=data,
            **iqargs)
```

When i executed the above example i am getting the folloing error

```
ERROR Error processing event handler: >
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "d:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sleekxmpp\xmlstream\xmlstream.py", line 1699, in           _event_runner
    func(*args)
    File "send_file.py", line 69, in start
    stream = self['xep_0047'].open_stream(self.receiver)
    File "d:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sleekxmpp\plugins\xep_0047\ibb.py", line 143, in    open_stream
    resp = iq.send(timeout=timeout)
    File "d:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sleekxmpp\stanza\iq.py", line 235, in send
raise IqError(result)
IqError
ERROR service-unavailable:
WARNING You should catch IqError exceptions
DEBUG Event triggered: presence
DEBUG Event triggered: presence_available
DEBUG Event triggered: presence
DEBUG Event triggered: presence_available
DEBUG Event triggered: presence
DEBUG Event triggered: presence_available
DEBUG Event triggered: got_online
DEBUG Event triggered: changed_status
DEBUG Event triggered: got_online
DEBUG Event triggered: changed_status
DEBUG Event triggered: changed_status
```